# Validating an entity using generated EdmScalarProperty

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework, with the classes generated.

The properties are generated with various attributes like this:

```
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
```

I know that MVC uses these attributes to apply validation, but I'm not using MVC.

Is there any way to validate the entities using these properties?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, EF validation is independent of MVC, you need read [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/27/ef-4-1-validation.aspx) from Microsoft EF team to get an understanding. MVC use attribute to apply client-side validation. This is optional and not required.

Comment: I read the post but it doesn't really explain how to initiate the validation.